# Copying files with execute permissions in Docker Image

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Seems like a basic issue but couldnt find any answers so far ..

When using ADD / COPY in Dockerfile and running the image on linux, the default file permission of the file copied in the image is 644.  The onwner of this file seems to be as 'root'

However, when running the image, a non-root user starts the container and any file thus copied with 644 permission cannot execute this copied/added file and if the file is executed at ENTRYPOINT it fails to start with permission denied error.

I read in one of the posts that COPY/ADD after Docker 1.17.0+ allows chown but in my case i dont know who will be the non-root user starting so i cannot set the permission as that user.

I also saw another work around to ADD/COPY files to a different location and use RUN to copy them from the temp location to actual folder like what am doing below. But this approach doesnt work as the final image doesnt have the files in /otp/scm

```
#Installing Bitbucket and setting variables  
WORKDIR /tmp
ADD atlassian-bitbucket-${BITBUCKET_VERSION}.tar.gz .
COPY bbconfigupdater.sh .

#Copying Entrypoint script which will get executed when container starts 
WORKDIR /tmp 
COPY entrypoint.sh .

RUN ls -lrth /tmp

WORKDIR /opt/scm 
RUN pwd && cp /tmp/bbconfigupdater.sh /opt/scm \
 && cp /tmp/entrypoint.sh /opt/scm \
 && cp -r /tmp/atlassian-bitbucket-${BITBUCKET_VERSION} /opt/scm \
 && chgrp -R 0 /opt/ \
 && chmod -R 755 /opt/ \
 && chgrp -R 0 /scm/bitbucket \
 && chmod -R 755 /scm/bitbucket \
 && ls -lrth /opt/scm && ls -lrth /scmdata
```

Any help is appreciated to figure out how i can get my entrypoint script copied to the desired path with execute permissions set.

Comment: normally i make the file executable locally and build the image. I am able to get executable file inside the docker. I simply copy as you are doing

Comment: Can you post the full Dockerfile?

Answer (score 36):

The default file permission is whatever the file permission is in your build context from where you copy the file. If you control the source, then it's best to fix the permissions there to avoid a copy-on-write operation. Otherwise, if you cannot guarantee the system building the image will have the execute bit set on the files, a `chmod` after the copy operation will fix the permission. E.g.

```
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

A better option with newer versions of docker (and which didn't exist when this answer was first posted) is to use the `--chmod` flag (the permissions must be specified in octal at last check):

```
COPY --chmod=0755 entrypoint.sh .
```

You do not need to know who will run the container. The user inside the container is typically configured by the image creator (using `USER`) and doesn't depend on the user running the container from the docker host. When the user runs the container, they send a request to the docker API which does not track the calling user id.

The only time I've seen the host user matter is if you have a host volume and want to avoid permission issues. If that's your scenario, I often start the entrypoint as root, run a script called [fix-perms](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base) to align the container uid with the host volume uid, and then run gosu to switch from root back to the container user.

Comment: Here's the relevant ticket for adding `--chmod` or similar functionality to the COPY command https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34819

Comment: `docker build` says Operation not permitted when I run this, any ideas?

Comment: @Squirrelkiller the user specified in the image (with `USER`) needs to have permission to modify file permissions (write access to the directory and file I believe, or you can be root).

Answer (score 14):

A `--chmod` flag was added to `ADD` and `COPY` instructions in [Docker CE 20.10](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/1492). So you can now do.

```
COPY --chmod=0755 entrypoint.sh .
```

To be able to use it you need to enable [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).

```sh
# enable buildkit for docker
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
# enable buildkit for docker-compose
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
```

Note: It seems to not be documented at this time, see [this issue](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2941).