# Why file's execute permission is not keep when copied into docker image during github action?

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I ensured that the local copy of `entrypoint.sh` referenced by the Dockerfile has execute permission. Below is the screenshot of the log of github action job that shows `entrypoint.sh` has execute permission. But, once the image is built and I try to run it `docker run...` I still get `unexpected - failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown` error.

The only way that `entrypoint.sh` did keep execute permission is by doing `RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh` inside Dockerfile.

Why `entrypoint.sh` did not keep its execute permission when copied into the image?

[image]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY entrypoint.sh /

# I HAD TO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OTHERWISE EXECUTE PERMISSION WOULD NOT BE SAVED
# RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-image.yml**

```
name: Docker Image
on:
  release:
    types: [published]

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository_owner }}/my_image

jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Entrypoint permission before
        run: ls -l
        working-directory: ./docker

      - name: Give entrypoint.sh execute permission
        run: chmod +x ./docker/entrypoint.sh

      - name: Entrypoint permission after
        run: ls -l
        working-directory: ./docker

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: ./docker
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          build-args: |
            "SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}"
```

Comment: Could you add `uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3` before `docker/login-action@v3` and give result of such?

Comment: adding `setup-buildx-action` helped. Can you explain why? I only understood that it somehow extends the docker build command. But, what it actually did to allow the file's permission to remain?

Comment: To be honest... It was lucky guess... I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558570/copying-files-with-execute-permissions-in-docker-image) and saw that without `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`  people had problems with permissions. Checked how to set it and I copied that...

But now I dug more, and... it seems that it's already built with buildkit :/

Comment: It seems that `docker` builder doesn't go with permissions, and `docker-container` (which is set with `setup-buildx-action`) does... But why... can't find anything ind docs